# Error: must rename columns with a valid subscript vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm just trying to import a kaggle data set to study R on and it's being a nightmare.

I'm trying to rename the columns in my data frame but I keep getting errors.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(janitor)
food_advs<- read.csv("CAERS_ASCII_2004_2017Q2.csv")
food_df <- data.frame(food_advs)
food_df %>% rename(food_df, Product = PRI_Reported.Brand.Product.Name, Industry = PRI_FDA.Industry.Name, Person_age = CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event, Gender = CI_Gender, Outcomes = AEC_One.Row.Outcomes, Symptoms = SYM_One.Row.Coded.Symptoms)



> food_df %>% rename(food_df, "Product" = "PRI_Reported.Brand.Product.Name", "Industry" = "PRI_FDA.Industry.Name", "Person_age" = "CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event", "Gender" = "CI_Gender", "Outcomes" = "AEC_One.Row.Outcomes", "Symptoms" = "SYM_One.Row.Coded.Symptoms")
Error: Must rename columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<
  RA_Report..                    : integer
  RA_CAERS.Created.Date          : character
  AEC_Event.Start.Date           : character
  PRI_Product.Role               : character
  PRI_Reported.Brand.Product.Name: character
  PRI_FDA.Industry.Code          : integer
  PRI_FDA.Industry.Name          : character
  CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event        : integer
  CI_Age.Unit                    : character
  CI_Gender                      : character
  AEC_One.Row.Outcomes           : character
  SYM_One.Row.Coded.Symptoms     : character
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: You already have the data in the lhs of `%>%` i.e. `food_df %>% rename(Product = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

```
food_df %>% 
    rename(Product = PRI_Reported.Brand.Product.Name,
           Industry = PRI_FDA.Industry.Name, 
           Person_age = CI_Age.at.Adverse.Event,
           Gender = CI_Gender,
           Outcomes = AEC_One.Row.Outcomes,
           Symptoms = SYM_One.Row.Coded.Symptoms
    )
```

Your mistake is in your usage of `%>%`; It is abundant to use `rename(data, ...)` when you already have `data %>%` before your call.